# javascript: At what situation i need to use void(0)

Tags: javascript

I just want to know at what situation I need to use 'void(0)'. When I happen to use this 'void(0)' in javascript code? Any help?

```
javascript:void(0);
```

Comment: create leader picture...

Comment: Never. [*void*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.2) is an operator, not a a function, so the grouping operator is redundant. `void 0` is sufficient and generally used as a short way to write `undefined` (it saves 3 characters and avoids use of the identifier *undefined*, which may have been assigned some value other than the *undefined* value).